# How to convert a string to int in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm declaring a class called Employee with the following details. For some reason I'm getting an error saying: cannot convert a string to int e.g `int empNo = input.nextLine();`

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Employee {
    private String empName, empDesig;
    private double bsal=0.0, ha=0.0, gsal=0.0;
    private int empNo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {          
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of employees");
        int empNo = input.nextLine();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Just use `input.nextInt();`. More importantly, read the [Scanner tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

Comment: i dont want it to go to the next line because im creating an array. i have this code but im getting error message.

Comment: The `nextInt()` method won't go to the next line if there are more tokens (text separated by "white space") to be found on the line.

Comment: I want to  instantiate an array in the next line e.g                                                    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter number of employees");
  int num = input.nextLine();
   
  int N[]= new int[3];

Comment: I got it work. Thank HoverCraft Full Of Eels. If I wanted to use int, i would need to change input.nextLINE(); to input.nextINT();..

Comment: As stated in the first comment to your question...